# Why I'm not able to display the success message in my simple CRM angular web application?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

In my Basic Angular app, I'm not able to display success message after writing the right code.

1)app.component.html

```
<h1 class="c1">{{title}}</h1>
<div *ngIf="success_msg;" style="background-color:aquamarine;">

User added successfully

</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

2. app.component.ts

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
          title = 'Simple_CRM_App';
          success_msg = true;
         }
   ```
3. Output File

[Angular App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqhJI.png)

Comment: Remove `template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>'` from AppComponent. Add with `templateUrl: './app.component.html'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with `template` Currently you have added the template within your component, so whatever you will add inside the `app.component.html` it doesn't work,

Now you have to either you can use `templateUrl` instead of `template` like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
   title = 'Simple_CRM_App';
   success_msg = true;
}
```

or If you wish to use only template then update your template like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
              <h1 class="c1">{{title}}</h1>
              <div *ngIf="success_msg" style="background-color:aquamarine;">
                User added successfully
              </div>
            `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use templateUrl instead of template

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```